# How to use react-popper with render props using functional component

Tags: reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

```
        `
        <Manager><div role="presentation"
                id="popover"
                className={popoverClasses}
                onClick={onDismiss}
                onKeyUp={onDismiss}
              >{backdrop && <div className={styles.popover__backdrop} />}
                <div ref={popoverRef}> --how to implement
                  <Reference>
                    {({ ref }) => {
    // how can we implement ref
                      ref = ref; -- how to implement
                      const targetProps = {
                        ref: setReferenceRef,
                        // Accessibility
//event handler
                        onKeyUp: (keyUpEvent) => {
                          if (
                            ['Enter', 'Space Bar', 'Spacebar', ' '].includes(
```

// key of event handler
keyUpEvent.key,
)
) {
if (!open) {
onEvent();
} else {
onReferenceClickClose();
}
}
},
[`on${event[0].toUpperCase()}${event.substr(1)}`]: !open
? onEvent()
: onReferenceClickClose(),
};
return (

<span
role="button"
className={styles.popover__reference}
tabIndex={tabIndex}
aria-haspopup="dialog"
{...targetProps}
>
{reference}

{refIcon}

);
}}


<Popper
placement={position}
modifiers={{
...modifiers,
preventOverflow: {
boundariesElement: boundaries,
},
}}
>
{({ ref, placement, arrowProps }) => (






{title && {title}}


{children(closePopover)}


)}





`